Issues with Using Lambda Functions and std::function in C++ with Clang 16
I am having trouble using lambda functions and std::function in C++ on my system. Although I am compiling with Clang 16 and specifying -std=c++11 or -std=c++17, the compiler fails with errors like:
•   no template named 'function'
•   expected expression for lambdas.
I have included  and ensured that the correct compiler is being used (/usr/bin/clang++). Despite these steps, the issue persists in both CLion and VS Code.
Could you please help me understand what might be wrong?
c++ /Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp -o oef8
c++ /Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp -o oef8
/Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp:9:39: error: no template named 'function'
    9 | void vul_array(int[],int[],int[],int ,function<int(int,int)> f);
      |                                       ^
/Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp:16:33: error: expected expression
   16 |     vul_array(a, b, c, GROOTTE, [](int a, int b) -> int{ return a + b;  });
      |                                 ^
/Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp:22:29: error: expected expression
   22 |     vul_array(a,b,c,GROOTTE,[](int a, int b) -> int{ return a * b;  });
      |                             ^
/Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp:28:29: error: expected expression
   28 |     vul_array(a,b,c,GROOTTE,[](int a, int b) -> int{ return a - b;  });
      |                             ^
/Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp:44:53: error: no template named 'function'
   44 | void vul_array(int a[],int b[],int c[],int grootte, function<int(int,int)> f) {
      |                                                     ^
5 errors generated.


Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre] (with emphasis on the minimal part) that generates the errors. And add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the errors.

Also please include exactly how you build the code, with verbose build-log output so we can see the flags and options passed to the compiler.

Did you include the correct header, and should you be full-qualifying std::function with the namespace?

"Although I am compiling with Clang 16 and specifying -std=c++11 or -std=c++17." The compiler output c++ /Users/sharekh/Downloads/UGent/MyProject/UGent/Reeks_B/oef8.cpp -o oef8 shows that you are not specifying -std=c++11 or -std=c++17.
